# write mouse data to USB driver, replacing mouse virtually

Tags: linux, automation, driver, mouse, hardware

I am looking to supply a USB driver with the data it would receive from a physically moving mouse. Essentially replacing a physical mouse. But since the data is delivered directly to the usb driver, it thinks there is a real mouse. I am not looking for an application which makes the mouse move in some other programmatic/emulated way. I want to deliver data to the usb driver that it would regularly receive from physical mouse.

Here is something that looks promising (looking for Unix but windows might work too)
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man4/mousedrv.4.html

Can anyone assist me on this?

Comment: I found some leads:
(http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x194.html)
(http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_5.htm)